# ContentLength error for Request Stream in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, webclient

I'm trying to get some data back from rest WS in C# but I'm getting this error:

> You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(order);
        string jsonResponseToString = "";
        HttpWebRequest request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myurl.com");
        request.Method = "POST";
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(json);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = @"application/json";
        try
        {                
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream str = response.GetResponseStream();
                var sr = new StreamReader(str, encoding);                    
                
                jsonResponseToString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                var result = new OrderResult();
                result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<OrderResult>(jsonResponseToString);
                if (str != null)
                {
                    str.Flush();
                    str.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // 
        }
```

The error is happening on this line:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
```

How can I solve this, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use `HttpClient`; it's much nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you need to write your bytes to the request before you can send it.

Call `GetRequestStream()` and write your bytes.

Comment: where should I call that method, before the 'using' statement? Thx for help

Comment: Before sending the request (`GetResponse()`).  Remember to dispose the stream.

Comment: I'm adding  request.GetRequestStream(); before GetResponse, it goes without error but then again I'm getting error on the using statement. As you can see from the sample I'm disposing the stream after I'm done using, when exactly should I dispose the stream? Thanks

Comment: You also need to write to the stream.